# Regarding putting break with an case

Tags: java

I was going through a code of switch conditional statement

```
char c1=65;
switch(c1){
  case 'A':
    System.out.println("one");
  default:
    System.out.println("two");
  case 'b':
    System.out.println("three");
}
```

While the outcome was 'one two three' but while debugging  I found that it first enters the case A which is the ASCII value 65 of A , but then it also executes all the remaining cases but if I put break; then it comes out , so does this means if we don't put break it will continue to execute all the cases please advise.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. This fall-through behavior is useful in some situations, but intentional use of the fall-through can also be a pain to debug when not properly documented. Some organizations use coding standards that actually prohibit the fall-through behavior and require a break terminating each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will continue to execute it until reaches break.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) you can read more info about switch Statement.

Comment: “It will continue to execute until it reaches break” or the end of the `switch` block.

Answer (score 6):

if you don't put **break**, all the rest cases after the matched case will be executed automatically. Control will come out of **switch case** in two cases:

```
1. When it ends.
2. When it finds a break.
```

Answer (score 2):

you may read [java language specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jls-7-mr3-fullv-oth-JSpec/JLS-JavaSE7-Full.pdf?AuthParam=1335682411_3bf1c8d4ac958c722bf01b735d4e4c72)  section 14.11 . Its clearly defined how switch block is executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Break is used to goto the end of [Switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement),Thus completing execution of the switch statement.

Not only Java,It is same across many languages.

Answer (score 1):

@user1351820, your understanding is correct. 
Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The *break statements are necessary* because without them, statements in switch blocks **fall through**: `All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.` 
The program [**SwitchDemoFallThrough**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/SwitchDemoFallThrough.java) shows statements in a switch block that fall through. The program displays the month corresponding to the integer month and the months that follow in the year.

Technically, the **final break** is not required because flow falls out of the switch statement. Using a break is recommended so that modifying the code is easier and less error prone. The default section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the case sections.

**Ref:** [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all then remaing cases **below the maching case** will execute.
If your matching case is last then only the matching case will excute or matching case is in middle cases above the matching case will not execute, but cases below matching case will execute along with matching case.

```
char c1=65; switch(c1)
{
   case 'B':
      System.out.println("three");

   default:
      System.out.println("two");

   case 'A':
      System.out.println("one");  
}
```

In this situation you output will be `one`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `case` statements fall through. If you are interested in the background reasons, this construct stems from C, which is also known as "assembler with macros", meaning that it is a very low-level language. The `switch` statement as defined in C is perfect for optimal implementation---with some constraints on the values being switched, it needs only two instructions: one for table lookup of the address where to jump, and one for the jump. After the jump execution just continues with no further intervention -- so an explicit `break` is needed to step out of the block.